# Time manipulation on ZkSync

Tags: blockchain, solidity, rollup, ethers.js, hardhat

I am a new one in zksync development, I try to test my smart contract using Dockerized setup but I have problem with time manipulation.

I tried to use

```
await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [60]); 60 sec
await provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [86400]);
```

but it give me

**Error: processing response error (body="{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"},"id":56}\n", error={"code":-32601}, requestBody="{"method":"evm_increaseTime","params":[1],"id":56,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://localhost:3050", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)**
Thanks in advice)